# Is there a way to compute the homotopy groups of spheres in Julia?

Tags: math, julia, symbolic-math, algebra

I want to treat [Algebraic topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology) on Julia. For example, I'd like to compute [the homotopy groups of spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres) (See 4.1).
Are there any packages or codes?

Comment: did you look at [HomotopyContinuation.jl](https://www.juliahomotopycontinuation.org/guides/installation/) ? or [TopOpt.jl](https://github.com/JuliaTopOpt/TopOpt.jl) ? I'm not familiar with your domain and theses packages but it might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but it's probably not what I need. I found [Kenzo software](https://github.com/gheber/kenzo) written by Common Lisp. This software is based on [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870884710188). So, if possible, I'd like to demonstrate the same algorithm for very easy examples in Julia , but I don't know yet how it is difficult.